# Azure APIM Import OpenAPI Spec Failing in GitHub Build Actions

Tags: github-actions, openapi, azure-api-management

After loggging into Azure from my GitHub Build action I am trying to update my APIM OpenAPI spec to keep it in sync with my source code.

I try to do this by executing the following:

`- name: Update APIM Specification uses: azure/CLI@v1 with: azcliversion: 2.0.72 inlineScript: | az apim api import --resource-group prod-rg --service-name MyAppAPI --path /myapp/v1 --specification-format OpenApi --specification-path ./openapi_spec.yaml --api-id my-app --subscription-required false`

And I was expecting the action to be performed successfully.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

`Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.0.72 ERROR: az apim: 'api' is not in the 'az apim' command group. See 'az apim --help'. Error: Error: az cli script failed.`

I have read the docs and It's not clear why this couldn't be available to run.
I am "running on":

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Comment: Azure CLI with version '2.0.72' is pretty old. The current version is '2.58.0'. Is this issue still present when you use the current Azure CLI version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli#august-04-2020 `az apim api import` was added only in version 2.10.0.